# CCPointFromString is crashing :( in cocos2dx 2.0.4

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

I am doing a CCPointFromString conversion but my coding crashing whenever I am trying to take input, Here is the code , what I am doing wrong?

```
CCPoint *temp = new CCPoint(oldLocationCon.x, oldLocationCon.y);

pointInsert->addObject(temp);

for(int i=0; i<pointInsert->count(); i++){

    CCString point = (CCString*)pointInsert->objectAtIndex(i);

    CCPoint savePoint= CCPointFromString(point->getCString());

}
```

Comment: Any logs, error messages?

Comment: See if `objectAtIndex(i)` is really a `CCString`, it may be another type of object.

Comment: Here is the one possible answer of the question: 

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/31789?r=31805

Answer (score 1):

```
CCArray * pointInsert = CCArray::create();
CCPoint * temp        = new CCPoint(0, 0);

pointInsert->addObject(temp);

for(int i = 0; i < pointInsert->count(); i++){

    CCString * point = static_cast<CCString*>(pointInsert->objectAtIndex(i));

    CCPoint savePoint= CCPointFromString(point->getCString());

}
```